# windows partition deleted by boot camp assistant but space is not restored

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition

I was trying to delete bootcamp drive , using bootcamp assistant while formating it hanged up along with my mac. i could not perform any action. (like cmd+q ) or open any other app .
so it was hanged i decided to force restart by pressing power button . mac restarted normally, bootcmap drive was deleted , but its space is also gone now.. there is no storage added to my macOs drive. 
and deleted drive is not appearing in diskutility

any idea on how to restore this lost space ?

heres the output from diskutil list

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   
disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         198.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +198.0 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            181.4 GB   
disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.7 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: Try entering the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` in a Terminal application window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by David Anderson in comment the solution to this problem was this command

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

No idea how it worked or what it does but i got my storage space back.